# GIT checkout -- twice

Tags: git, git-checkout

When I want to revert changes of a file I use 
`git checkout -- path/to/file.ext`. But somehow I have to execute the command twice now.
After the first checkout `git diff` shows nothing but the file is still listed as modified on my stage.
Only after the second checkout the file is removed from the stage.
Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: I have the exact same issue on Win10. Locally changed file on WC is overwritten by the file in staging area when I `git checkout -- file` for the first time, but it still looks modified by `git status` until I `git checkout -- file` for the second time. But `git diff` shows no diff even for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

The command:

```
git checkout -- path/to/file.ext
```

copies the contents of `path/to/file.ext` from the staging-area to the work-tree.  It does not change the contents stored in the staging-area, and running it twice *should* make no difference at all: copying from staging-area to work-tree, then copying again from staging-area to work-tree, should result in the same work-tree contents on the second copy as on the first.

---

Note that there is a *third* version of the file—well, we should really call it the *first* one—which is the copy that is in the current *commit*.  When you check out some commit, Git:

- copies the content of each file stored in that commit into your staging-area, and (at the same time)
- copies the content of each such file into your work-tree.

This means that there are *three* active versions of the file at all times:

- `HEAD:path/to/file.ext`: this one is read-only, permanently stored in the commit, in a special, compressed, Git-only form.  Use `git show HEAD:path/to/file.ext` to see it, for instance.
- `:path/to/file.ext`: this one is read/write, and not permanent.  It is stored in the staging-area (also called the *index*, or sometimes the *cache*), also in a special compressed Git-only form.  The difference between this and the first file is that this one, you can overwrite, and whatever is in the index/staging-area copy is what will go into the next commit you make.  Use `git show :path/to/file.ext` to see this copy.

  - Using `git add path/to/file.ext` copies the work-tree version to the index / staging-area.
  - Using `git checkout -- path/to/file.ext` copies the index / staging-area version to the work-tree.
  - Using `git reset path/to/file.ext` copies the `HEAD:path/to/file.ext` version from the commit to the index / staging-area, without affecting the work-tree version.
- Last, there is the work-tree version, `path/to/file.ext`.  This file is stored in your computer's normal format, so that you and your computer can work with it.

(If you want to copy the `HEAD` version of the file to *both* the index/staging-area *and* the work-tree, you can do that with `git checkout HEAD path/to/file.ext`.)

---

Note that when you run `git status`, this runs, in effect, two diffs:

1. `HEAD` vs index: whatever is different here is "staged for commit".
2. index vs work-tree: whatever is different here is "not staged for commit".

You never see the index / staging-area directly: you only see it in comparison to either the `HEAD` commit, or in comparison to the work-tree.  This makes sense because, in a large project, the index / staging-area has thousands of files all the time, but usually only a few are different from either the current commit, or the work-tree, or both.

Comment: Nice answer + 1 for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to git reset the file.

```
git reset path/to/file.ext
```

This will unstage a file. `git checkout` will discard the changes in working directory.
In your case if it's staged you can do a reset first to unstage it and then git checkout the file.

It's not the intended behavior of checkout to do it twice to unstage.

Comment: I did not mention the git reset will affect the work-tree version. I said it will unstage a file what you have staged by git add

Comment: Oh, right, you said "git *checkout* will discard the changes...". I'll delete the comment, but I do think it would be clearer if you put the "git checkout" part in computer-y-font (backquotes).